# How to convert int (int64) into uint16 in golang?

Tags: go

I can 100% guaranty the value of input int variable is always unsign(positive) and less than int16.

How can I convert this int type variable to uint16?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
// convert the type and assign to new variable or pass as a parameter. 
var i int
...
u := uint16(i)
foo(uint16(i))
```

Comment: Nitpicking: Go does not have type casts; what we're dealing with here is called type conversion. Go is explicit about this sort of thing.

Comment: Appreciated.  Edited the example.  I hadn't noticed the distinction but sure enough, I could not find the term cast used by the Go authors, just by examples supplied by others.

Answer (score 6):

You need to check that the number is not negative and that it is <= 0xFFFF and then cast it to an unsigned 16 bit int.